# undefined is not a function error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the below error is my AngularJs app.

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$rootScope.shareImageNow (index.controller.js:150)
```

I am not sure what's the reason after doing some Google research.

**controller.js File**

```
app.controller('ViewCtrl', function($rootScope, $state, $scope, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout, Service) {

    var appUrl = "https://play.google.com";

    $rootScope.shareNow = function() {

        var message = "xx";
        var subject = "yy";

        Service.share(message, subject, null, appUrl);

    }

    $rootScope.shareImageNow = function() {

        var imageIndex = 0;

        var imgUrl = $rootScope.itemData[imageIndex]['url'];

        var message = "xx";
        var subject = "yy";

        Service.share(message, subject, imgUrl, appUrl);

    }
});
```

**service.js File:**

```
module.service('Service', function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSocialSharing) {

    $rootScope.share = function(message,subject,file,link) {

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $cordovaSocialSharing
                .share(message, subject,file,link);
        }, false);

    }
}
```

The error is shown at the below line in controller.js file.

```
Service.share(message, subject, null, appUrl);
```

Comment: Which one is line 150 in the index.controller.js

Comment: Sorry @DavidGrinberg. I have updated the question now. The error shown is at Service.share(message, subject, null, appUrl);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're registering the `Service` service, but not defining any methods on it.

You're also doing a lot of things with `$rootScope`, which I'd question why you're doing that.

Anyways, you can define your service as follows, and you will not get the error at `Service.share()`

```
module.service('Service', function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSocialSharing) {

  var share = function(message,subject,file,link) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          $cordovaSocialSharing
              .share(message, subject,file,link);
      }, false);

  };

  return {
      share: share
  }
}
```

Comment: Is my way of using a service complety wrong? I have other methods in the service and they all work fine.

Comment: In short, yes, the way you're using the service is completely wrong.  `$rootScope` should almost *never* need to be used -- that's what services are for.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. This is my first app using Angular. So, if I have more functions in the service, I should be returning all of them at the end as shown. is that so? Can you point me to a tutorial where this is explained? not the official one plz.

Comment: See this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/makuwifaxa/1/edit?html,js,output).  I tried to demonstrate a little.  Notice in service, there are two functions, but I only return one.  I'm able to call what I've returned, `share()`, but unable to call `privateFunction`, as it is not exposed publicly.  [www.egghead.io](http://egghead.io) is a good place to start for free AngularJS tutorials

Comment: Thanks @tom. I will check on this.